Pumpkin can’t grow beyond 4 weeks
I have a pumpkin plant that I have grown from seeds. Infact it is a combination of multiple plants, since I sprinkled multiple seeds and they have now interlocked. The plants have grown quite large and vines up an adjacent wall and across the surrounding floor.
The problem that I find, the small pumpkins begin growing at the neck of the flower, then after approximately 4 weeks of growth the flower turns brown, shrivels and dies. Once this occurs the pumpkin seems unable to survive and begins to shrivel and will eventually fall off.
I have ensured that the plant has well hydrated- 2 x per day. I am in Northern Thailand which has recently endured a heavy rainy season over the last couple of months, meaning the plants should really have never been without enough water.
How can I keep my pumpkins alive and growing? The plant itself looks strong, and the leaves are green and branches thick. The flowers never seem to last very long, even when they don’t have little pumpkins behind them.
3 Weeks of visible pumpkin growth

4 Weeks of visible pumpkin growth


Have you been pollinating them?

@SirThinksalot No. Water only, fresh new earth occasionally and in the later stages some coffee ground added to the soil.

When a female opens, search the vines for a male flower. Rip the petals off of it and rub the pollen-covered part in the middle on the stigmas in the centers of the female flowers.

Thank you. I am going to accept this answer as I have now researched pollinating pumpkin flowers and it appears to match my problem exactly.
